# driver.page_source returns only meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, meta-tags, meta

I want to scrape one website, to get the page content with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://adress:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
link = 'website_url'
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
print((s.encode("utf-8")))
driver.quit()
```

this is what receive:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

I also tried a lot of different ways, Luminati, proxy newipnow, phantomjs, but does not work, any suggestions what else i can try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

### `<meta name="ROBOTS" content="value">`

This meta tag conveys the different search engines about the actions they are allowed and not allowed to take on a certain page. This meta tag can be placed anywhere within the `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

**Note**:: As this `<meta>` tag does not have a site-wide effect it can contain different values on different pages of the same website.

The valid *values* are:

- `Index` (default value)
- `Noindex`
- `None`
- `Follow`
- `Nofollow`
- `Noarchive`
- `Nosnippet`

These values can be combined as well to form the desired valid meta robots tag.

Example:

- `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`
- `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />`
- `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noarchive" />`

---

### [content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"](https://www.hermesthemes.com/meta-robots-noindex-nofollow/)

The `NOINDEX` value conveys the search engines **NOT** to index the page, so the page should not show up in search results. The `NOFOLLOW` value conveys the search engines `NOT` to follow or discover the pages that are *LINKED TO* on this page.

Web developers adds the *NOINDEX* , *NOFOLLOW* meta robots tag on development websites, so the search engines accidentally doesn't start sending traffic to a website that is still under construction.

---

### Why are you seeing?

The reason can be either of the following:

- You are trying to execute your *auomated tests* within *Development Environment*.
- Development Team have accidentally added this tag to live website.
- Development Team have forgot to remove it from live websites after going live.

---

### Reference

[What is the meaning of the meta name "robots" tag](https://www.metatags.org/meta_name_robots)

---

### Outro

[Using the robots meta tag](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html)